# Why would ISC dhcpd ignore vendor options?

Tags: dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

I'm trying to use an existing `dhcpd` to autoconfigure Raritan networked PDUs. This works roughly like PXE booting: there are additional DHCP options that direct the device to fetch a config file via TFTP. However, it uses vendor DHCP options to do this.

I have defined the option space, and a new class for the PDUs. I can see that my class is being matched (I set the DNS and domain-name differently inside the class, and those options are sent). However, the vendor-specific options are not sent (checked with `dhcpdump`). The server has no problem with the config though (that it logs anyway).

What can cause it to not send vendor options?

```
set vendor-string = option vendor-class-identifier;

option space RARITAN code width 1 length width 1 hash size 3;
option RARITAN.pdu-tftp-server code 1 = ip-address;
option RARITAN.pdu-update-control-file code 2 = text;
option RARITAN.pdu-update-magic code 3 = text;

class "PDUs" {
    match if option vendor-class-identifier = "Raritan PDU 1.0";
    vendor-option-space RARITAN;
    option vendor-class-identifier "Raritan PDU 1.0";
    option domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1;
    option domain-name "pdu.net";
    option RARITAN.pdu-tftp-server 10.251.0.9;
    option RARITAN.pdu-update-control-file "raritan-update.cfg";
    option RARITAN.pdu-update-magic "20180822-0005";
}
```

Nothing in any of the existing scopes uses `vendor-option-space`, so I don't think there are any conflicts there.

Comment: I would at least try to be consistent in your capitalisation `vendor-option-space` or `option space`  `RARITAN` might not match `class "raritan"` because of case sensitivity.

Comment: They are different objects. Also, the server does match the class - I get the non-vendor options. The case/name of the option-space matches in both cases. As far as I understand it, the class could be called "huskies". Is that incorrect?

Comment: I have little to no idea how the vendor encapsulated options are supposed to be implemented or work actually, but the difference in case is something that just caught my eye. From past experience I know that things such as meaningful white space and case (in)sensitivity in unexpected places can make for difficult debugging and those are a  blind-spot of mine when I think I followed [an example](https://www.isc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/dhcp41options.html#VENDOR%20ENCAPSULATED%20OPTIONS) almost verbatim.

Comment: gotcha... for the sake of argument, I just checked, and it doesn't make a difference what the class is called.

Comment: I'd do a quick packet capture on the dhcp server to ensure the devices are actually sending "Raritan PDU 1.0" as the vendor.  Edit: Nevermind, just noticed you said the class was matched.

Comment: Is it possible that there exist a limitation in dhcpdump? What does tcpdump/wireshark show? Perhaps the vendor specific options are sent to the PDUs but they incorrectly process them (for whatever reason).

Comment: I believe it's just a wrapper around tcpdump, but I've just checked with tshark and see the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should check 2 things:

- your Raritan client sends Option 43 (Vendor Specific Option) in DHCPREQUEST, and
- you are not hacking option 43 in your config anywhere else.

I hit the same issue and after few hours I found in my huge `dhcpcd.conf` with thousand of clients line `option cisco-wlc-encap code 43 = encapsulate cisco-wlc` which discarded any other attempts to set Option 43 by class and vendor-option-space syntax.